# Rails 3 Comparing foreign key to list of ids using activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, in-clause

I have a relationship between two models, **Registers** and **Competitions**. I have a very complicated dynamic query that is being built and if the conditions are right I need to limit Registration records to only those where it's Competition parent meets a certain criteria. In order to do this without select from the Competition table I was thinking of something along the lines of...

```
Register.where("competition_id in ?", Competition.where("...").collect {|i| i.id})
```

Which produces this SQL:

```
SELECT "registers".* FROM "registers" WHERE (competition_id in 1,2,3,4...)
```

I don't think PostgreSQL liked the fact that the in parameters aren't surrounded by parenthesis. How can I compare the Register foreign key to a list of competition ids?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can make it a bit shorter and skip the collect (this worked for me in 3.2.3).

```
Register.where(competition_id: Competition.where("..."))
```

this will result in the following sql:

```
SELECT "registers".* FROM "registers" WHERE "registers"."competition_id" IN (SELECT "competitions"."id" FROM "competitions" WHERE "...")
```

Comment: I love succinct code, I think this is the answer I'll go with.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
competitions = Competition.where("...").collect {|i| i.id}
Register.where(:competition_id => competitions)
```